# Buffering in km in NAD83 QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I need to create a 32.1869 km (20 miles) buffer around my attributes, but the problem is the CRS needs to stay in NAD83. Is there a work around so I will be able to create buffers in km but still have the CRS with the units in degrees?

Comment: you have to reproject to a CRS that handles meters as a measuring units for the coordinates, and that preserve the NAD83 datum

Comment: What coordinate system is your source data in?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: EPSG:4269 - NAD83 over over the US

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Make a copy of your dataset into UTM or LCC
2. Change the **project** CRS to that projection
3. Create the buffer in that projection
4. If necessary, use `Dissolve` to get a single non-overlapping buffer
5. If necessary, densify the buffer with a factor of 10 or more
6. Save the buffer under another filename and CRS set to NAD83
7. Remove the UTM/LCC layers
8. Set project CRS back to NAD83

Comment: What would be  good UTM to use over the US?

Comment: You did not tell the extent of your data. For the whole US, LCC would be better.

Comment: I apologize I am very new to QGIS

Comment: LCC (Lambert conformal conical) is a coordinate system, EPSG:102009.

Comment: Sorry I've run into a problem, when I reproject the buffers back into NAD83, they are not over moving over the right points. They are also remaining in a group over lapping each other.

Comment: You have to densify the buffer, and maybe dissolve too. Then use `Save As...` to reproject to NAD83.